# Creating multiple data frames from single data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

[click here to see dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMGFZ.png)

I have a data frame with 1738 rows. I want to create 1738 data frames consisting of these rows keeping the column header the same. How can I do that?

Comment: Why? and where do you propose to store them? Why can't you just reference them as `df.loc[i] for i in df.index`? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is to say you almost surely don't need it and you shouldn't be doing it. Please show us the surrounding lines of code so we know the context? (For example, if you want to run a function on each row of a dataframe, use `df.apply(yourfunc, axis=1)`)

Answer (score 0):

If the original dataframe is `data`

```
column_list = data.columns.tolist()                                   #get column names as list
for index,row in data.iterrows():                                     #iterate through rows
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_list)                        #make new dataframe
    new_df = new_df.append(pd.Series(row,index = column_list),ignore_index = True) #insert the row in newdataframe
    new_df.to_excel(str(index)+".xlsx")                               #output newdf as rownumber
```

This should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily using **DataFrame.copy()** .

The copy will have same structure and all the data type for the headers will be preserved

let's day **df** is the original dataframe. So for creating a copy of dataframe:

df_copy = df.copy()

if **deep == True** then a different copy of dataframe will be created and any change made in original or copied dataframe won't affect any of them. **By default deep = True.**

But if **deep == False** only references to the dataframe is created. That means any changes made to the original dataframe will be reflected to copied dataframe and vice versa is also true.

For reference read the documentation
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html